# Curl API call in PHP

Tags: php, curl, graphql

I'm new to PHP and trying to make a request to a third-party API using curl. This is what I am trying, but it is just responding with what is on the API's root endpoint.

```
$service_url = 'http://api.kivaws.org/graphql';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data = array(
        'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
        'Origin' => 'http://api.kivaws.org', 
        'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate', 
        'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36', 
        'content-type' => 'application/json', 
        'accept' => 'application/json', 
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache', 
        'Connection' => 'keep-alive', 
        'data' => '{"query":"{
          loans (filters: {gender: male, status:funded, country: [\"KE\", \"US\"]}, sortBy: newest, limit: 2) {
            totalCount
            values {
              name
              status
              loanAmount
            }
          }
        }","variables":null,"operationName":null}'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}
curl_close($curl);

echo $curl_response;
```

Comment: Can You pls post what is the end-point response?

Comment: And what desired output you want?

Comment: hello @Brett I got this reponse from your Api curl is this correct?
**{"data":{"hello":"Welcome to Kiva's GraphQL API!"}}**

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm getting. I want to be getting a json response of the loans specified in the data section of the query.

Comment: @Brett I got this :-
error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: 1

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be doing the trick: using `curl_setopt` to set few important things, like `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `True` so that it will return us the result in the body, and then encoding the query using `json_encode`.

```
$service_url = 'http://api.kivaws.org/graphql';

$curl = curl_init($service_url);

$curl_post_data = array("query" => '{loans (filters: {gender: male, status:funded, country: ["KE", "US"]}, sortBy: newest, limit: 2) {totalCount values { name  status loanAmount }}}');
$data_string =  json_encode($curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additional info: ' . var_export($info));
}
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl_response;
echo $info;
```

This returns me:

```
{"data":{"loans":{"totalCount":40425,"values":[{"name":"Davis","status":"funded","loanAmount":"100.00"},{"name":"James","status":"funded","loanAmount":"100.00"}]}}}
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks a ton.